# User activity hours

Tags: feature-request, timeline, activity-summary, suggested-edit-stats

On the user activity page it would be nice to be able to see what hours of the day a person tends to be active. This would give one a good idea of whether the person is ignoring your answer (or question) or are just asleep and haven't even seen it yet.

Comment: That's a very poor indication of whether something is seen or not. I may be active without looking at my notifications. I may also choose to postpone replying to something later because I'm active now but I'm short on time. I don't really see how that affects you either way - you're powerless to do anything about the situation.

Comment: What would be a sign they didn't ignore your answer? Keep in mind that voting, accepting and commenting is not required at all.

Comment: I dont know what you people arent getting. If they are asleep then I can go do something else. If not then I can keep checking back to see if they have responded. The system forced me to add the second part of the question. Forgive me if it wasnt fully thought out. It was an after thought. I didnt even want to put it in the question. I was forced to do so.

Comment: @R.Emery _"If they are asleep then I can go do something else. If not then I can keep checking back to see if they have responded."_ You can do _something else_ anyways, no matter if that person is asleep or not. If they choose to respond, you'll (usually) be notified in your inbox, in case they don't respond, you can't even force them if they're currently or recently active. So what?

Answer (score 7):

For the use case of seeing whether someone may have seen your question/answer, there is a more accurate way: the last active time on the profile page.

For instance, [yours](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/839523/r-emery?tab=profile) currently shows the following:

[image: Profile text including "Last seen 12 mins ago"]

Note that it's updated at most every 15 minutes, so it may be slightly out of date for very recent activity.

Comment: Also, I don't really know how it counts "last seen". Last thing was posted? Last time the user had a tab open? I frequently leave tabs to SO open on the new questions page and come back to get the see the questions that were added while I wasn't looking at said tab.

Answer (score 4):

The least person who is relevant to indicate the quality of your answer is the OP of the question, but the community of the site you posted on.
I experienced that even after years I have posted an answer, some people apparantly found it useful (or not), and up-/downvoted my post.

The goal here isn't primarily to help the poster of a question, but to give value for anyone who's researching for the same or a similar problem in the long term.

---

Also such feature would be very inaccurate, think about people who work in changing shifts.

> This would give one a good idea of whether the person is ignoring your answer (or question) or are just asleep and haven't even seen it yet.

OPs are already notified by new answers, comments or other activity on their posts. They are free to ingnore these notifications. E.g. think about a highly active question (maybe posted years ago), not every OP is willing to check the umpteenth response to their question, or they simply don't have the time to do so.

Implementing such would be just wasted dev time for no value.

Answer (score 2):

User privacy. I wouldn't want you to know what times I am active.